# Is there a way to insert a $name in a modal

Tags: php, html, css

I have packages on my store. The names, prices, description, etc.. are defined by variables. $name $price $small_desc

I've made a modal, and I'm trying to use those "variables" in it. This way when a player click for more informations, it will show a different package name on each modal.

The issue is, right now it's only displaying '.$name.'

Here you can visualize it by clicking on a package.
https://royalkingdom.net/store/?cat=1

I've tried inserting the modal in a php section but it didn't work.
I've also tried moving the location of my modal in my code and it didn't work.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      '.$name.'
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      Modal Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        while($post=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $image=$post['imageurl'];
                            $name=$post['name'];
                            $text=$post['description'];
                            $price=$post['price'];
     $small_desc = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $text), 0, 15))."";
     $it = exif_imagetype($image);

echo'
  <div class="package">                      
  <div class="package-image">
    <img src="'.(isset($image) && $image!="" && ($it == 1 || $it == 3 || $it == IMG_JPEG) ? $image : "img/404.jpg").'" class="item-img">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Click for Details</span>
 </div> 
<div class="info">
  <div class="text">
    <div class="name">'.$name.'</div>
    <div class="price">'.$price." " .$currency_simbol."USD".'</div> 
    <div class="buy">
    <a href="./product.php?item='.$name.'" class="buy">Buy</a>
</div>
</div> 
</div>   
</div> ';
```

I'm looking to have my "variables" display when I open a modal. This way each packages modal will have a different title, description, price, etc...

Comment: A typo?  You appear to have forgotten your `<?php ?>` tags.  Just putting PHP code directly into the HTML isn't going to execute that code.

Comment: you dont need to use echo for all html code. close php `?>` and write html. if you want to echo a var in html just use `<?=$var?>`

Comment: Ok now it works, but my variable act weird :/ If if put title, it put the title of the last package everywhere :/ @David

Comment: @SpikeyHunter: That sounds like something worth describing and demonstrating in detail in the question.  Currently the question only shows the aforementioned typo, and the comment has little if anything to do with that.  What "title"?  What "package"?  How does it "act weird"?  Try to be as clear and descriptive as you can in the question.

Comment: If you visit https://royalkingdom.net/store/?cat=1 you'll understand more :) So basically the problem is, my modal displays the informations $name, $small_desc from the last package that's displayed on the page, in all the modals. What I need is to have 1 modal ''template'' and the information inside it such as $name, to be the good one displayed.